# Sizzle instead of sound when recording with ALSA

Tags: alsa

I'm working a lot with ALSA and I don't know what I did wrong but when I record with:

```
arecord --channels=1 --duration=5 --format=dat --vumeter=stereo test.wav
```

...and play it back I only get some noise, whereas it worked before.

So I reset ALSA with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils reset
sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils restart
```

A message indicates that I reset ALSA successfully

`[ ok ] Resetting ALSA...done`.

But I still have noise when I play back what I have recorded. What could be causing the noise, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Please read the answer here, http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/sound-recording-using-python/9829#9829

Answer (score 1):

Try using `alsamixer`, you may have a source that is on making all that noise. You can mute individual sources using this app.